Could not write JSON: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` not supported by default SpringBoot
I am getting error: Could not write JSON: Java 8 date/time type java.time.OffsetDateTime not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling. But i have already added that module and configured it seemingly correctly according to everyone on the internet but it does not work.
I have registered the time module at:
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();
        return mapper;
    }
}

And i have imported the module at my pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

I have ran ObjectMapper.findModules(); and it finds the module. I have also added a breakpoint to see if the Objectmapper is ran and it is. But i still get error: Could not write JSON: Java 8 date/time type java.time.OffsetDateTime not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
at this point:
PlannedMaintenance maintenance = new PlannedMaintenance();
        maintenance.setEquipmentId(Long.parseLong(equipmentId));
        maintenance.setPlannedStartTime(plannedStartTime);
        maintenance.setPlannedEndTime(plannedEndTime);
        maintenance.setCreated(OffsetDateTime.now());

        boolean isInserted = plannedMaintenanceDAO.save(maintenance);
        StompHeaders replyHeaders = new StompHeaders();
        replyHeaders.add("status", isInserted ? "success" : "error");
        replyHeaders.add("correlation-id", headers.get("correlation-id").get(0));

        List<PlannedMaintenance> maintenanceReturn = plannedMaintenanceDAO.findAll();
        stompService.sendMessage(headers.get("reply-to").get(0), maintenanceReturn, replyHeaders);

With model PlannedMaintenance:
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PK")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PLANNED_START_TIME", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime plannedStartTime;

    @Column(name = "PLANNED_STOP_TIME", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime plannedEndTime;

    @Column(name = "ACTUAL_END_TIME")
    private OffsetDateTime actualEndTime;

    @Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED")
    private OffsetDateTime updated;

    @Column(name = "EQUIPMENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long equipmentId;

I have tried 4 different version of the JacksonConfig, i have tried diffrent versions of the module but nothing has worked and any of the other people on the internet have not given me a solution that worked.
I am using SpringBoot 3.1.10

Post full stack trace of your exception.

You don't need to override whole bean. Providing module is enough:
    @Bean
    public Module javaTimeModule() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        return module;
    }


Spring Boot 3.1.10 supports JSON serialization and deserialization of all temporal types introduced in Java 8 by default. This can be easily verified by opening Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder. This is a helper class in Spring designed to conveniently configure and instantiate an ObjectMapper for working with JSON when using the Jackson library. In Spring, it simplifies configuration by allowing you to specify settings for an ObjectMapper in one place, which makes it useful when working with JSON serialization and deserialization.
public class Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder {

  // ...

  private void registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(MultiValueMap<Object, Module> modulesToRegister) {
      Class kotlinModuleClass;
      Module kotlinModule;
      try {
          kotlinModuleClass = ClassUtils.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module", this.moduleClassLoader);
          kotlinModule = (Module)BeanUtils.instantiateClass(kotlinModuleClass);
          modulesToRegister.set(kotlinModule.getTypeId(), kotlinModule);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException var6) {
      }

      try {
          kotlinModuleClass = ClassUtils.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule", this.moduleClassLoader);
          kotlinModule = (Module)BeanUtils.instantiateClass(kotlinModuleClass);
          modulesToRegister.set(kotlinModule.getTypeId(), kotlinModule);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException var5) {
      }

      if (KotlinDetector.isKotlinPresent()) {
          try {
              kotlinModuleClass = ClassUtils.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule", this.moduleClassLoader);
              kotlinModule = (Module)BeanUtils.instantiateClass(kotlinModuleClass);
              modulesToRegister.set(kotlinModule.getTypeId(), kotlinModule);
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException var4) {
          }
      }
  }
}

Here we see that Spring itself registers the necessary modules
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule

Therefore, no additional actions are required from you.
